# save python output to log

Tags: python, logging, variables

I have a python script the runs this code:

```
strpath = "sudo svnadmin create /svn/repos/" + short_name
os.popen (strpath, 'w')
```

How can I get the output of that command stored in a variable or written to a log file in the current directory?

I know, there may not be an output, but if there is, I need to know.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277866/python-subprocess-module-looping-over-stdout-of-child-process, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880918/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-exe-to-a-file-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `'r'` mode to open the pipe instead:

```
f = os.popen (strpath, 'r')
for line in f:
    print line
f.close()
```

See the documentation for [`os.popen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen) for more information.

The [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module is a better way to execute external commands like this, because it allows much more control over the process execution, as well as providing access to both input and output streams simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to write to the command, then just change the 'w' to 'r':

```
strpath = "sudo svnadmin create /svn/repos/" + short_name
output = os.popen (strpath, 'r')

for line in output.readlines():
    # do stuff
```

Alternatively if you don't want to process line-by-line:

```
strpath = "sudo svnadmin create /svn/repos/" + short_name
output = os.popen (strpath, 'r')

outtext = output.read()
```

However, I'd echo Greg's suggestion of looking at the subprocess module instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in your bash-part:

```
strpath = "sudo svnadmin create /svn/repos/" + short_name + ' > log.txt'
```