# How do I run psinfo.exe and pipe the output to a file?

Tags: command-line-arguments

I would like to run the free Microsoft executable `psinfo.exe` and pipe the output to a file, embedded in a python program. I have been able to run the psinfo.exe file from a python program, but piping the output of psinfo into a file does not work.

If I run the simple batch file from the Windows command line:

`psinfo.exe > filename.txt`

Then the output of psinfo will be piped into the file filename.txt. The psinfo utility lists computer information, such as free disk space percentage and other information. If I try to use a one line batch file to pipe the psinfo data into a file, and run the batch file within Windows, it works, piping the data into a file. However, if I run the batch file from python, then the data will not pipe into a file.

How can I either run a batch file or the psinfo.exe directly and have the psinfo data pipe into a file running the batch file or psinfo.exe within a python program?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880918/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-exe-to-a-file-in-python

Comment: I already tried that method, and it did not work. The psinfo.exe can use several switches. The "-a" switch is not one of them. When the switch "-a" is used in the code: os.system("psinfo.exe -a > filename.txt"), an empty file is created.

Answer (score 0):

```
user = 'username'
passw = 'password'
logfile = '\path\to\logfile.txt'
host_info = subprocess.run(['psinfo', '\\\\' + hostname, '-u', user, '-p', pwd, '-d', '-nobanner'], stdout=logfile, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

I use the above example all the time.  This makes use of the subprocess library, which has more merit in this use case considering you're trying to run a platform-specific executable.