Print on a shell in python
I have converted a .py into an .exe.
In my .py I handle the occurance of an exception and I have a print with a message.
Of course when I run the .py on Python Idle shell, I see the message printed out.
The same doens't happen when the .exe is executed.
Is there another way to print the same message when the .exe is executed?

You can save your messages into a file.
I would recommend to use "logging" library.
The following question will give you good start on that.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386698/how-to-write-to-a-file-using-the-logging-python-module

However if you want to redirect the output of .exe to a file in python, then check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880918/how-to-redirect-the-output-of-exe-to-a-file-in-python

uhm no this wasn't the solution I was looking for but you gave me the idea of using an .txt where log the exception error. Thanks

do you execute .exe manually in console/terminal or you click on it? print() is for programs which you run manually in console. If you click then you should convert to  GUI using tkinter PyQt, etc, and display own window with text - but they work in different way.

I have converted a .py into an .exe. How? Provide a minimum Python program (perhaps one containing only a print), show how you compiled it into a self-contained binary, and demonstrate that the print does not work then.
